# Github Copilot activation failed when extension is installed

Tags: github-copilot

> GitHub Copilot could not connect to server. Extension activation failed: "getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN api.github.com"

I signed out and signed in to GitHub copilot to regenerate a new token but the issue still persists.

I also restarted my IDE and laptop even and I am still getting the failed activation error.

Comment: Have you googled this issue before posting it on this platform? Which IDE do you use?

Comment: Here is a discussion with some pointers: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/7704

In my case the extension in VSCode had to be reloaded (I assume because of an upgrade).